# Как правильно создавать делать партиции по времен в postgresql

Tags: база-данных, postgresql, best-practice, partition

У меня есть таблица вроде такой:

```
CREATE TABLE user (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(50),
    last_name VARCHAR(50),
    created_at TIMESTAMP
)
```

Я хочу сделать партицирование по колонке `created_at`. В некоторых источниках говорится, что лучше делать партицирование по дате без времени, а не `timestamp`'у. Это должно уменьшить количество вероятных проблем. Значит ли это, что мне необходимо завести отдельную колонку, вроде `created_at_date`, и писать в нее дату без времени и портицировать ее?

Но ведь для этого необходимо будете еще каждый раз прописывать дополнительный параметр в `select`, что замедляет запрос + добавляет человеческий фактор. К сожалению, не хватает опыта понять до конца какие есть плюсы и минусы у такого решения и стоит ли это делать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PostgreSQL без разницы обрабатывать partition constraint по дате или по timestamp. Или ещё по какому признаку. Хоть по вычисляемому выражению. Если под гипотетическими вероятными проблемами подразумевались таймзоны - то дата от таймзоны ведь тоже зависит.

А начать я хочу, впрочем, с обратного вопроса: зачем вы хотите партицировать пользователей по created_at? У вас сотни гигабайт пользователей в этой таблице и вы хотите хранить только зарегистрировавшихся за последние несколько лет, а остальных удалять из этой базы? Какую проблему вы хотите решить партицированием?

---

Если же у вас действительно есть обоснование зачем вам партицирование, то вот пример с двумя партициями:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    id SERIAL,
    name VARCHAR(50),
    last_name VARCHAR(50),
    created_at TIMESTAMP
) PARTITION BY range (created_at);

create table users_2019_09 partition of users for values from ('2019-09-01') TO ('2019-10-01');
alter table users_2019_09 add primary key (id);
create table users_2019_10 partition of users for values from ('2019-10-01') to ('2019-11-01');
alter table users_2019_09 add primary key (id);
```

Аналогично добавляются дальнейшие.

Обращаю внимание, что в postgresql 11 primary key может быть объявлен в самой партицированной таблице, но тогда он должен содержать и признак партицирования. Например, `primary key(id,created_at)`. Обычно это не нужно и можно добавить `primary key` на сами разделы, что я и демонстрирую в примере. Однако поиск по id при этом будет просматривать все партиции.

> необходимо будете еще каждый раз прописывать дополнительный параметр в select, что замедляет запрос + добавляет человеческий фактор

При работе с партицированной таблицей необходимо указывать параметр партицирования всегда. При том именно в том виде, в каком признак описан в выражении `PARTITION BY`. Иначе база будет вынуждена просматривать каждую партицию. Стоимость разбора пары десятков байт дополнительного условия `where` - понятное дело на этом фоне будет равна ничему.